# Import different file depending on environment

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app

I'm using Create-React-App. I have 2 static JSON files with data which is different depending on the environment they run in.

What is the best approach to importing the files based on the environment the application runs in?

I have this but it doesn't look right, any other advice?

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
        import data from './data/devData';
    }
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        import data from './data/prodData';
    }
```

Comment: Maybe using `require` or dynamic `import` (using Babel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one file config with keys for example "default" and "production". Once import with file, check process.env and return actual config object.

```
const config = require('./data/config.json');

function getConfig() {
   let customConfig = config['default'];

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        customConfig = config['production'];
    }  

    return customConfig;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something similar to this.

Comment: One thing to be aware when using this process, is that you end up with both sets of ENV properties being deployed to you ENV.  If someone got access to your source map, from your production website, it may expose your other ENV's attributes that may include sensitive data.  Best way is still to either swap it our at compile/bundle time or use require or a dynamic load option.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea - add to your wabpack [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias)

```
 resolve: {
     alias: {
       'config/data': path.resolve(__dirname, `./data/${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
     }
 }
```

and call it from component this way:

`import { data } from 'config/data';`