# Custom conditional file extensions in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo

I have a React project (specifically a React Native for Web with expo) that I'd like to have custom file extensions so that I can switch which files are compiled depending on a setting, e.g. an environment variable.

So I have three files

```
foo.ts
foo.company1.ts
foo.company2.ts
```

So for example, if `CUSTOMER=company1`, then only `foo.company1.ts` will be compiled and the other two will be ignored. `import * from './foo'` would import `foo.company1.ts` (so, I don't want to have to use explicitly [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import))

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about using dynamic imports? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: @evolutionxbox I would like the import statements to be standard. I've seen this solved elsewhere, like when `.web.ts`, `.android.ts`, `.ios.ts` are resolved to the right platform. Those don't require any special import.

Comment: you can create an compiler alias. here is an example with webpack https://stackoverflow.com/a/63553446/7387397

Comment: @Sysix that looks better. I'll give it a try. But I don't need it just for a single file, I want it as a genera rule for all files. I'll see if I can get it working